# Entity Framework - multiplicity constraint violated

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

This question has been asked a lot, and I tried all of the solutions, they seem to be not working.

Models are:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
  public virtual Profile Profile { get; set; }
}

public class Profile
{
   public virtual string Id { get; set; }
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration>());
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(x => x.Profile).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.User);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Profile>().HasRequired(x => x.User).WithRequiredDependent(x => x.Profile);
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

The code that is failing is:

```
 foreach (var user in context.Users.Include(x => x.Profile).ToList())
 {
     //I commented everything here while debugging  
 }
 context.saveChanges();
```

So, the code is failing after a simple select....

**EDIT:**

Error is

> Multiplicity constraint violated. The role 'Profile_User_Source' of the relationship 'Thanker.Models.DAL.Profile_User' has multiplicity 1 or 0..1.

**EDIT2**
For some reason DefaultConstructor for entities is getting called there. Any ideas why?

Comment: Have you checked for duplicate profiles in your database?

Comment: Yes, Profiles and Users are unique...

Comment: You are materializing entities (`ToList()`), so the constructor is called.

Answer (score 2):

The reason was that my default constructor for Profile and User was making changes to the entities. For some reason default constructor is called even when a simple secect is made.